# syntax error while executing sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting Syntax error in one of the sql statement, this is like below statement(sample)

```
Declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL =' select Case When isnull(M_loc.BeginAge, '')='' and  isnull(M_loc.EndAge, '')='' 
         then '' 
         else Convert(nvarchar(5),M_loc.BeginAge)+' To '+Convert(nvarchar(5),M_loc.EndAge)
          End AS [Age_Limit]'


sp_executesql (@SQL)
```

I am getting below error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'To'.

Comment: that syntax attempt makes no sense

Comment: What is To? And why are you using ISNULL with constants as the first value?

Comment: This is just a sample code,Query i am using in DB is like that and this is just a part of whole query that's why i written a sample code for this.

Comment: @user2613346 - Who wrote that query? The `CONVERT` in SQL does not work in that way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: I'm assuming what you wanted to write is `SELECT CASE WHEN myColumn = 10 THEN 20 ELSE myColumn END AS myColumnCalc FROM myTable`. You're using the most complex way to try and switch 2 values, and you're missing a FROM clause. Lastly, use `EXEC sp_executesql @sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you are missing "+"s and "'"s:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(10, '''') = '''' AND ISNULL('''', '''') = '''' THEN ''''
        ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), 10) + ' + ''' To ''' + ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), 20)
    END;';
SELECT @SQL;
EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: Although it will obviously need changing as you have changed your question...

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code if you are using sql server 2012 or above:

```
Case When isnull(M_loc.BeginAge, -1)=-1 and  isnull(M_loc.EndAge, -1)=-1
 then '' 
 else CONCAT(M_loc.BeginAge,' To ',M_loc.EndAge) End AS [Age_Limit]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be in this also we can do

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(10, '''') = '''' AND ISNULL('''', '''') = '''' THEN ''''
            ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), 10) + ' + ''' To ''' + ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), 20)
        END;';
    SELECT @SQL;
    EXEC(@SQL);
```